# A javascript regex to include alphanumeric and special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need a javascript regex to include alphanumeric and special characters only. I tried below regex but it is not working.

```
/^(?!.*(<|>)).*[a-zA-Z0-9 \\\\@!#$%^&*()_+-={}:;'\",.?|\[\\]\/~`\n]+$/
```

Comment: Can you include a list of desired accepted and rejected outputs? Maybe even a list of rules?

Comment: ^[ A-Za-z0-9_@.#&+-]*$

Answer (score 0):

To accept Special characters

**[^\w\s]** matches any non-alphanumeric and non-whitespace character.

**\S** matches any non-whitespace character.

**.** matches any character except newlines.

**[\S\s]** matches any character in a JavaScript regex.

**alphanumeric Strings are matched like this:**

```
 ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

It matches any string that only contains of the listed chars and is at least one char long.

With special chars it would work the same way.

But what do you consider to be a special char?

For !@#$%^&*()+=-[]\';,./{}|":<>? – being the set of special chars, the regex would look like this:

```
  ^[@!#\$\^%&*()+=\-\[\]\\\';,\.\/\{\}\|\":<>\? ]+$
```

Again, all the allowed characters are listed. The ones used within regexes as commands or quantifiers have to be escaped with a .

Comment: would it work for `"abc@%()()"`????